# Play / Slick / SQLite Evolutions Not Working

Tags: sqlite, playframework, slick

I created a `SQLite` Database like this in my `Ubuntu` from terminal:

```
$ sqlite users.db
```

Then I moved the `users.db` file to `projectDir/conf/application.conf`.
Later I wrote an evolution but it didn't get applied to my `users.db` database when I view my database through `DBeaver`.

Here is my `application.conf` file

```
play.http.secret.key = "changeme"

play.i18n {
  langs = [ "en" ]

}
play.filters {
  enabled += filters.ExampleFilter

}

play.evolutions.db.default {
  enabled = true
  autoApply = true
  autoApplyDowns = true
}

slick.dbs.default {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile$"
  driver = "slick.driver.SQLiteDriver$"
  db.driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC"
  db.url = "jdbc:sqlite:/home/saad/play-scala-starter-example/conf/users.db"
}

play.assets {
  path = "/public"
  urlPrefix = "/assets"
}
```

And here is my `build.sbt`

```
name := """play-scala-starter-example"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.7")

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.2.3"

libraryDependencies += evolutions
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.0"
)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.23.1"
)
```

Here is my `1.sql` file, I have tested the code there are not errors.

```
# --- !Ups

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Email varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Authenticated boolean
);

INSERT INTO Users(LastName, FirstName, Password, Email, Authenticated) VALUES ('Saad', 'Ali', 'spadsdditcom', 'asdasdasd', 1);

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users
```

After I do `sbt run`, `index` page opens and there are no errors but evolution is not applied either as seen from `DBeaver`.

**My question is, what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What version of play do you use and in where do you put evolutions file?

Comment: I figured it out, I placed `1.sql` in `conf/dafault.evolution` instead of `conf/dafault/evolution`, probably that was causing the problem. I am using `Play 2.6.20`.

Comment: Yes, it should be `conf/default/evolution`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I placed `1.sql` in `conf/default.evolution` instead of `conf/default/evolution`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `conf/evolutions/default`?